# How to add to a classname in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

hi how can I add to classname to this code:

```
  {
    title: <span className='Time'>Time</span>,
    key: 'time',
    render: ({ created_at }: any) => {
      return utilService.dayjs(created_at).format(`YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss A`)
    },
  },
```

I need to float left for date `YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss A' cuz of that I want to add classname to output.

Must be in reactjs

Comment: Looks like you already have one?:  `className='Time'`  It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: for the output of date I havent.

Comment: You probably want to _align_ left. Floating is a very specific thing whereby content flows around an element. I agree, though--your question isn't clear.

Comment: @Samet: And how is that output rendered?  What is `utilService` and what does it do?  How is this code used?  The *only* actual UI code shown here is one JSX `<span>` element, which has a `className`.

Comment: yes I want to align left but for just one row. cuz of that I want to add a class. to output.

Comment: 2022/01/04 08:43:45 AM this is the output of utilService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the return in div or span:

```
{
  title: <span className='Time'>Time</span>,
  key: 'time',
  render: ({ created_at }: any) => {
    return (
      <div className="your-className">
        {utilService.dayjs(created_at).format(`YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss A`)}
      </div>
    );
  },
},
```

Comment: I should get it output like that 2022/01/04 08:43:45 AM. div directly push to front like a span not the output.

Comment: wrap the date in curly braces {utilService.dayjs(created_at).format(`YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss} inside of the div. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes it worked great thanks!